# How can i remove trait method collisions using traits and classes that are in different namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, traits, collision

I keep getting an php error indicating that either the method is not in the current class or there is a collision. See error:

```
Trait method callMe has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on Src\Classes\A in
C:\wamp\www\src\classes\a.php on line 72
```

I have tried but I could not find a solution. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
trait A // namespace Src\Traits;
{
     function callMe()
     {}
}
trait B // namespace Src\PowerTraits;
{
     function callMe()
     {}
}
class A // Namespace Src\Classes;
{
    use \Src\Traits\A;
    use \Src\PowerTraits\B {
        A::callMe insteadof B::callMe;
    }
}
```

When i try

```
A::callMe insteadof callMe;
```

i get the following error (understood, it is obviously in the wrong namespace):

```
Could not find trait Src\Classes\callMe
```

Also tried:

```
\Src\Traits\A::callMe insteadof \Src\Traits\B::callMe (error, syntax error);
\Src\Traits\A::callMe insteadof B::callMe (error: wrong namespace);
\Src\Traits\A::callMe as NewA (error, collision warning);
\Src\Traits\A::callMe as \Src\Traits\A::NewA (error, syntax error);
```

Left alone, gives the collision warning:

```
Trait method callMe has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods
```

How can override a trait method when the traits and the calling class are all in different namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to `A::callMe insteadof B::callMe`

- you cannot name a method following the scope resolution operator `::` (Paamayim Nekudotayim) when using `insteadof` because PHP will look for a method by the same name. `A::callMe insteadof B;`
- you need to either use/import/alias the class name, or reference the fully qualified class with namespace `\Src\Traits\A::callMe insteadof \Src\PowerTraits\B;`

Demo: https://3v4l.org/g1ltH

```
<?php

namespace Src\Traits
{
    trait A
    {
        function callMe()
        {
            echo 'Trait A';
        }
    }
}

namespace Src\PowerTraits
{
    trait B
    {
        function callMe()
        {
            echo 'PowerTrait B';
        }
    }
}

namespace Src\Classes
{
    class A
    {
        use \Src\Traits\A;
        use \Src\PowerTraits\B {
            \Src\Traits\A::callMe insteadof \Src\PowerTraits\B;
        }
    }
}

namespace
{
    (new \Src\Classes\A)->callMe();
}
```

> Trait A